# Stuck in integration(1)

Tags: integration

I've been stuck on this integral for a long time and have no idea whatsoever on how to even proceed.
$$\int_4^{10} \dfrac{[x²]}{[x²-28x+196]+[x²]}~dx~~?$$ where [.] is the GIF"

I dont know how to put mathematical characters, sorry

Also, any advice on how to proceed on similar sums containing the greatest integer function would be massively appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is just the area under a set of rectangles isn't it?

Comment: @Paul: "just" that but computing the innumerable rectangles is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

There is a trick. By the symmetry $x+y=14$

$$\int_4^{10}\frac{\lfloor x^2\rfloor}{\lfloor(14-x)^2\rfloor+\lfloor x^2\rfloor}dx=\int_4^{10}\frac{\lfloor(14-y)^2\rfloor}{\lfloor y^2\rfloor+\lfloor(14-y)^2\rfloor}dy$$

and the answer is $3$.

Comment: How did you think of doing x+y=14

Comment: Can't say i got this tho

Comment: @Kaustav: don't you see the $14-x$ ?

Comment: Yeah i got it now. Thanks!

Comment: More generally, we have $\int_a^b f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) dx$